# Get multiple data from same table with different Id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get 9 columns say(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) from table `user` where id = id and 2 columns say(j,k) from same table `user` but from admin id. Is it possible ?

I tried `UNION` but it's giving me error saying columns should be same.

I also tried:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from user where id=id JOIN select j, k from id=admin_id limit 1
```

But any of it is not working. how can I achieve this ?

EDIT: @Cetin Basoz has answered my doubts.

Comment: I really do not understand how the end result should llook like. Can you pls provide sample data and expected output based on that data?

Comment: Please share more details. How do these tables look like? How does the persisted data look like? How should the returned data look like?

Comment: return data should be a single row with all the 11 columns where 9 col come from user id and rest 2 from admin id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have constant values for the missing columns. ie:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i from user where id=someid 
union 
select j, k, null, null, null, null, null, null, null from user 
where id=admin_id;
```

EDIT: It works as suggested:

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3f2a11c016e2f3b18e26f3c7c34aa4e)

Your question is not clear and looks like you are after a union, but maybe you were trying to say you want to get back something like:

a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k instead? If so, then:

```
select * from
(SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i 
from _user where id=someId) t1
cross join
(SELECT j,k 
from _user where id=admin_id) t2;
```

Comment: this is not working and only outputting first 9 columns with `someid`

Comment: @naive_user, then there isn't any with admin_id.

Comment: there is, this query is not working

Comment: @naive_user the query in this question works, just may not produce the output you are expecting as the answerer did not understand fully what you are looking for or you are providing wrong filter parameters.

Comment: I'm trying to get `j, k` from admin table and populate the response in my api. It's not working for me

Comment: @naive_user it works. I added a dbfiddle demo for you.

Comment: it's coming under `a,b`

Comment: @naive_user, I think you couldn't describe your problem in the first place. You should provide sample data and expected output. Anyway, the edited one is what you are asking and has nothing to do with UNION.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN id = @some_user_id THEN a END) AS a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id = @some_user_id THEN b END) AS b,
--     ...
       MAX(CASE WHEN id = @some_user_id THEN i END) AS i,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id = @admin_id     THEN j END) AS j,
       MAX(CASE WHEN id = @admin_id     THEN k END) AS k
FROM source_table
```

If specified `@user_id` not exists then according column will produce NULL.

If the table is empty then the output will be empty too.

---

> is there a way to do this any shorter way ? – naive_user

```sql
SELECT MAX(a) AS a, MAX(b) AS b, ..., MAX(k) AS k
FROM ( SELECT a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,NULL AS j,NULL AS k
       FROM sourcetable 
       WHERE id = @some_user_id 
     UNION ALL
       SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,j,k
       FROM sourcetable 
       WHERE id = @admin_id ) AS subquery
```

Comment: is there a way to do this any shorter way ?

Comment: @Akina, if it was what he wanted then UNION is an overkill (and also MAX()).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Agreed, in this particular case this is excess, and the latter solution in your answer is the best variant. My answer is a pattern for such tasks primarily.